# What does "hybridGCD" method do in Java BigInteger Class?

Tags: java, biginteger

I was looking at Java BigInteger gcd method source code. I found hybridGCD() method that was not defined anywhere in the Class.

here is the link:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

```
public BigInteger gcd(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.signum == 0)
        return this.abs();
    else if (this.signum == 0)
        return val.abs();

    MutableBigInteger a = new MutableBigInteger(this);
    MutableBigInteger b = new MutableBigInteger(val);

    MutableBigInteger result = a.hybridGCD(b);

    return result.toBigInteger(1);
}
```

The gcd method was not responding for an hour for two fairly large numbers (containing million digits each).

Comment: I don’t know what exactly hybridgcd does, but the running time makes sense. Most likely it’s Euclid algorithm. It performs multiple a % b operations, which should be pretty expensive (n^2 or n^3, iirc, where n is length). The algorithm performs this operation O(n) times, so it’ll be pretty long.

Comment: I once looked at GCD algorithms for very large operands. I found that GMP (Gnu Multiprecision library, a C/C++ library) including a superior algorithm to other BigInt libraries. Not just faster because it was native code but faster because it was a better algorithm. The source code and notes for `mpn/gcd.c` might be a good resource if you're determined to implement something faster than `hybridGCD()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is defined here (since it is part of MutableBigInteger):

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/MutableBigInteger.java